# Modify .htaccess to Open .txt.gz Files Directly in Browser

Tags: .htaccess, gzip

I have some .txt files on my server, but some of them have been gzipped to make .txt.gz files.

If a user clicks on the .txt files they open fine in the browser, but if the user clicks a .txt.gz file it prompts them to download the file and then requires them to gunzip it before opening.

Since modern browsers can gunzip content directly, I'd like for them to just open in the browser, jus tlike the .txt files.

I created a rule in my .htaccess file:

```
<FilesMatch '\.txt\.gz$'>
ForceType text/plain
</FilesMatch>
```

But this still prompts me to download the .txt.gz file.

Is there a way I can open the .txt.gz files directly in the browser.

Comment: Those are actually two different compression algorithms. "gziped" files cannot be "unzipped", if that refers to the classical "zip unzip", they need to be "gunzipped"...

Comment: Also it is questionable if it makes sense to actually compress the files in the first place. Modern browsers and http servers support transport level compression. Which is completely transparent. And results in the same benefit of reduced transport bandwidth.

Comment: @arkascha fair point on gunzipping vs unzipping. I changed my post to avoid the confusion.

Comment: The files are gzipped to reduce the file storage size.